# Count elements and then return the index of a particular element?

Tags: jquery

I have a slideshow driven by thumbnails below the main image. I have a fixed width and more thumbnails than will fit in this space.  What I want to do is a simple check what number thumbnail I'm on and if it's more than will fit in the space adjust the margin, so what I want to know is:

I know how to count the number of elements with .length, but how do I then check the index of the element with the active class?

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li class='active'>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The method is... drumroll... [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: Well, they can't all be Millennium Prize questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [.index() docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/) state:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
>
> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

So this would work for you:

```
$('li.active').index()    // Returns 3
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mfczB/)**

Remember that the count is zero-based.